# Postgresql: is it possible to tell in which column the search string was found?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, where-in

how to tell in which column the search string was found?

My query

```
 select DISTINCT t1.id,
 t2.position ,
 t3.name ,
 t4 age

 FROM table1 AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN  table2 AS t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_id 
  LEFT JOIN  table3 AS t3  on t3.fk_id = t2.fk_id 
 LEFT JOIN  table4 AS t4  on t4.fk_id = t3.fk_id 
 WHERE 
  t2.position like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) 
  OR          
  t3.name like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25'])
  OR
  t4 age like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would copy the conditions in the `select`:

```
select . . .,
       ((case when t2.position like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) then 'position;' else '' end) ||
        (case when t2.name like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) then 'name;' else '' end) ||
        (case when t2.age like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) then 'age;' else '' end) 
       ) as matching_columns
. . .
```

Comment: is it possible to do it for to_tsquery full text search?

Comment: WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', f_concat_ws(' ', t2.position,t2.name,t2.age))
    @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'Real:* ');

Comment: @MoHalem . . . That logic would also work in the `select`, but you would need to check each column independently.  If this remains an issue, ask another question, specifically about full text search.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind repeating the conditions:

```
select x.*,
       position like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) as found_in_position, 
       name like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) as found_in_name, 
       age like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) as found_in_age
from (
  select DISTINCT 
       t1.id,
       t2.position,
       t3.name,
       t4.age
  FROM table1 AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN  table2 AS t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_id 
    LEFT JOIN  table3 AS t3  on t3.fk_id = t2.fk_id 
    LEFT JOIN  table4 AS t4  on t4.fk_id = t3.fk_id 
  WHERE 
    t2.position like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25']) 
    OR          
    t3.name like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25'])
    OR
    t4.age like ANY(['Real Estate Agent ','25'])
) x;
```

The derived table (aka sub-select) is necessary, because DISTINCT operates on all expressions of the SELECT list, and adding the flags could change the outcome of that.

Comment: is it possible to do it for to_tsquery full text search?   WHERE to_tsvector('simple', f_concat_ws(' ', t2.position,t2.name,t2.age)) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'Real:* ')